# How to get the player rank from there stats in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code i am trying to get the play speed rank from mysql.

Mysql Table Called Accounts

```
 Username | Speed
 -----------------
 Player1     21
 Player2     52
 Player3     33   

 Player2 52(Ranked:1)
 Player3 33(Ranked:2)
 Player2 21(Ranked:3)

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts") or die (mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          $username= $row[username];
 $speed = $row['speed'];
  }
```

sorry i have been trying different ways but i cant get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts ORDER BY speed DESC") or die (mysql_error());

$rank = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $username= $row[username];
    $speed = $row['speed'];
    $rank++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just sort them by speed:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts ORDER BY speed DESC") or die (mysql_error());
$prev_rank = 0;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          $username= $row['username'];
          $speed = $row['speed'];
          $rank = ++$prev_rank;
  }
```

Read about [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use it:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts ORDER BY speed DESC") or die (mysql_error());
```